# The Application Control navigator replaces the entire page instead of acting like a navigation pane

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to create a navigation pane using the Application Layout control.  I added a Navigator control to the Left Column with several nodes.  I added an Editable Area control to the center column facet.  When I select a link in the navigation pane, instead of the content appearing in the 'center column' facet (keeping the navigation pane visible), the entire page gets replaced with the page from the selected link.  I've tried partial refresh of the center column facet but it still just jumps out of the initial navigation page.  I've check the xPages Extension Library guide and few on-line resources but don't see mention of anything special to set to make this work.

thanks
clem

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've put the Navigator control on just one XPage. As Stephan says, look at the way the ExtLib Sample database is done. The Navigator is on all XPages, and the links are links off to another XPage. They're not designed to put the contents of another XPage into the centre panel.

If the navigation is the same for all XPages, you can add the Navigator to the Custom Control containing your Application Layout control.

It may also be worth looking at the NotesIn9 episode on the Application Layout control http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/01/31/notesin9-042-xpages-and-application-layout-control/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Extlib sample database. One of the examples is the dynamic content control. It allows to show different custom controls based on a selection condition. That might be what you need.

The Navigator is designed to navigate between pages, not inside a page.